# Firestore subscribe fires automatically

Tags: angular, firebase, rxjs, ionic3, google-cloud-firestore

**Temp Solution:**

I have done very **ugly hack** here. Do you know a better solution to this issue?

```
const sub = this.budgetGroups$.subscribe(res => {
      if (res.length > 0) {
        this.showToast.showErrorToast('Budget Group already exists');
        sub.unsubscribe();
        return false;
      } else {
        this.budgetGroupProvider.createTempBudgetGroup(name);
        this.isBudgetGroupAvailable = true;
        sub.unsubscribe();
      }
    },
      err => { console.log(err); sub.unsubscribe() },
      () => sub.unsubscribe()
    );
```

**Original Issue:**

I'm using firestore with my app. I have seen a very critical issue with below implementation. It is working fine when I create a budget group. After that, I have deleted that budget group using firebase console. At that time this method fires again and again. Could you tell me how to handle this? Hope I'm using `subscribe` wrongly here.

*page.ts*

```
 createBudgetGroup(name: string, projectId?: string) {
         this.budgetGroups$ = this.budgetGroupProvider.getSpecificTempBudgetGroup(name).valueChanges();
         this.budgetGroups$.subscribe(res => {//here is the issue
          if (res.length > 0) {
            this.showToast.showErrorToast('Budget Group already exists');
            return false;
          } else {
            this.budgetGroupProvider.createTempBudgetGroup(name);
            this.isBudgetGroupAvailable = true;
          }
        },
          err => console.log(err)
        );
      }
```

*provider.ts*

```
  getSpecificTempBudgetGroup(name: string): AngularFirestoreCollection<BudgetGroup> {
    return this.fireStore.collection<BudgetGroup>(`members/${this.authenticationProvider.member.id}/budgetGroups`, ref => ref
      .where('name', '==', name)
    );
  }
```

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/377#issuecomment-261480358

Comment: Those operators are not working with.Could you tell me why?  `this.budgetGroups$.first().subscribe(res => {` . I have used `import { first } from 'rxjs/operators';`. The error is `Property 'first' does not exist on type 'Observable<BudgetGroup[]>'` @yurzui

Comment: Try `import 'rxjs/add/operator/first';`

Comment: Oh.. It is working. Could you tell me why this is not working? `{ first } from 'rxjs/operators';`. @yurzui

Comment: Your solution is perfect. Hope you'll put it as an answer. Thanks a lot @yurzui

Comment: `{ first } from 'rxjs/operators';` its lettable operator. They are used through `.pipe(operators)` Something like `.pipe(first())` https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/lettable-operators.md#usage

Comment: Great. I have used like this and working fine. `this.budgetGroups$.pipe(first()).subscribe(res => {` . Hope you'll help me to close this issue @yurzui

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase observable will never be completed because it is a real time database.

You can use `first` operator to overcome it

**rxjs^5.5**

```
import { first } from 'rxjs/operators';

this.budgetGroups$.pipe(first()).subscribe
```

For earlier rxjs versions

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/first';

this.budgetGroups$.first().subscribe
```

Comment: Perfect. Learnt a lot. Thanks a lot :)